# polymer serve vs. static web server

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli

**What kind of magic is `polymer-serve` doing that I don't get with a simple, static web server?**

I just started with a simple "hello world" project. When I run `polymer serve` I'm able to browse to the page at http://localhost:8000/example.html and it works great. If I use [`static-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server) and browse to the same page, I get an error message in Chrome.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/lit-element". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Here's example.html, which was copied right out of the [README](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element).

```html
<script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import { LitElement, html } from "@polymer/lit-element";

  class MyElement extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
      return {
        mood: { type: String }
      };
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.mood = "happy";
    }

    render() {
      return html`
        <style>
          .mood {
            color: green;
          }
        </style>
        Web Components are <span class="mood">${this.mood}</span>!
      `;
    }
  }

  customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
</script>

<my-element mood="happy"></my-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are imported by name instead of by path

check for instance this [reference](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2018-02-26-3.0-preview-paths-and-names)

From it

> This change brings Polymer in line with standard npm practice, and
>   makes it easier to integrate Polymer with other tools and projects.
>   However, **because browsers don't yet support importing modules by name**,
>   it means you'll need a transform step to run Polymer modules natively
>   in the browser. The Polymer CLI and related tools are being updated to
>   do this transformation automatically.

running *polymer build* should create converted files (referenced by path)